# Is it okay to call initialize() to initialize a view?

Tags: backbone.js

In my Backbone app, I have the following

```
  playlistView = new PlaylistView({ model: Playlist });
  Playlist.getNewSongs(function() {
    playlistView.initialize();
  }, genre, numSongs);
```

`Playlist.getNewSongs()` is called back when some ajax request is finished. I want to re-initialize the view then. However, I believe the way I'm doing it leads to this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745122/stoplistening-race-condition) of a  view listening to a same event twice. Is calling `initialize()` like this acceptable? If not, what should I do instead?

**Update:**

I wrote this [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/instant-music/ehebnoicojclpjjblbacdjmpjpkocmml) in Backbone to learn Backbone, and it's in a design hell at the moment. I am in the middle of refactoring the entire codebase. The snippet below is my PlaylistView initialize() code block.

```
  var PlaylistView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#expanded-container',

    initialize: function() {
      var playlistModel = this.model;
      var bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();

      if (!bg.player) {
        console.log("aborting playlistView initialize because player isn't ready");
        return;
      }

      this.listenTo(playlistModel.get('songs'), 'add', function (song) {
        var songView = new SongView({ model: song });
        this.$('.playlist-songs').prepend(songView.render().el);
      });

      this.$('#song-search-form-group').empty();
      // Empty the current playlist and populate with newly loaded songs
      this.$('.playlist-songs').empty();
      var songs = playlistModel.get('songs').models;

      // Add a search form
      var userLocale = chrome.i18n.getMessage("@@ui_locale");
        var inputEl = '<input class="form-control flat" id="song-search-form" type="search" placeholder="John Lennon Imagine">' +
          '<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="open-favorites"><span class="search-heart-icon fa fa-heart"></span></a>'+
          '<span class="search-input-icon fui-search"></span>';
      }
      this.$('#song-search-form-group').append(inputEl);
      var form = this.$('input');
      $(form).keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.charCode == 13) {
          var query = form.val();
          playlistModel.lookUpAndAddSingleSong(query);
        }
      });

      // Fetch song models from bg.Songs's localStorage
      // Pass in reset option to prevent fetch() from calling "add" event
      // for every Song stored in localStorage
      if (playlistModel.get('musicChart').source == "myself") {
        playlistModel.get('songs').fetch({ reset: true });
        songs = playlistModel.get('songs').models;
      }

      // Create and render a song view for each song model in the collection
      _.each(songs, function (song) {
        var songView = new SongView({ model: song });
        this.$('.playlist-songs').append(songView.render().el);
      }, this);

      // Highlight the currently played song
      var currentSong = playlistModel.get('currentSong');
      if (currentSong)
        var currentVideoId = currentSong.get('videoId');
      else {
        var firstSong = playlistModel.get('songs').at(0);
        if (!firstSong) {
          // FIXME: this should be done via triggering event and by Popup model
          $('.music-info').text(chrome.i18n.getMessage("try_different_chart"));
          $('.music-info').fadeOut(2000);
          //console.log("something wrong with the chart");
          return;
        }
        var currentVideoId = firstSong.get('videoId');
      }

      _.find($('.list-group-item'), function (item) {
        if (item.id == currentVideoId)
          return $(item).addClass('active');
      });

    },
```

Comment: Calling `initialize` like that is not "normal". Off hand, it sounds like you're trying to do too much in `initialize`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not wrong but probably not a good practice. You did not post the code in your `initialize` but maybe you have too much logic here.

If you are simply initializing the view again so that the new data is rendered, you should use event listener as such:

```
myView = Backbone. View.extend ({
    initialize : function() {
         // We bind the render method to the change event of the model. 
         //When the data of the model of the view changes, the method will be called.
         this.model.bind( "change" , this.render, this);   

        // Other init code that you only need once goes here ...
        this.template = _.template (templateLoader. get( 'config'));
    },

    // In the render method we update the view to represent the current model
    render : function(eventName) {    
        $ (this.el ).html(this .template ((this.model .toJSON())));      
        return this;        
    }

});
```

If the logic in your `initiialize` is something totally else, please include it. Maybe there is a beter place for it.